# How can I test a method with a Task return type?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, task

I am trying to test a method whose signature is of the form

```
public async Task<List<int>> MethodToBeTested()
```

I have written a unit test as follows

```
[TestMethod] 
public async Task MethodToBeTestedSuccess()
{
Task<List<int>> results = await MethodToBeTested()
......
}
```

If the method's return type had been a generic List of integers I would have performed the following steps to test the output

```
List<int> results = MethodToBeTested();
int numberOfResults = results.Count;
Assert.AreEqual(numberOfResults,2300);
```

My question therefore is: how can I test the async method, whose return type is wrapped in a task, and validate that 2300 results have been returned?

If I try the strategy I attempted on the generic list of integers I get the error: cannot convert the method group Count to non-delegate type int.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the unit-testing framework is `async`-aware (if you are doing asynchronous unit testing, one hopes it is :) ), then you should be able to just fix your compiler error:

```
[TestMethod] 
public async Task MethodToBeTestedSuccess()
{
    List<int> results = await MethodToBeTested()
    ......
}
```

In other words, given the signature you have shown, then if you `await` the method call, the result type is `List<int>`, not `Task<List<int>>`, and you should declare the variable to receive the result accordingly.